# How do you solve a linear recurrence relation for $a_{n}$ given the solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I'm a beginner who is starting to learn about linear recurrence relations. I've just come across a problem where I'm not sure how to progress.

Going off of my notes linear recurrence was solved using this form

$a_{n}= C_{1}a_{n-1}+C_{2}a_{n-2}$

where the C's are constants

that form is then manipulated and used with the quadratic formula ... etc..

My problem is since this method uses $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, I'm not sure how to solve a linear recurrence problem for a formula that doesn't have those.

For reference here is the problem

$a_{n} = 2^{n}(1 + (−2)^{n})$

What is the method used to solve these types of recurrence problems?

**After some clarification I realized that the problem is asking for me to find the linear recurrence of the form $a_{n}= C_{1}a_{n-1}+C_{2}a_{n-2}$, but I'm still not sure how to do this**

Comment: There is no *recurrence*.

Comment: If $a_n$ is defined in terms of $n$ then that is it. Maybe you can express it in nicer ways but recursion requires to express it as $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$.

Comment: here is the entire question in case i left out some crucial information.             
Find a linear recurrence relation for an that satisfies the formula $a_{n} = 2^{n}(1 + (−2)^{n})$ State the initial conditions for a0 and a1. Does this change anythinh?

Comment: both are defined by the formula provided its given for $n=0,1,2,...$, just compute them: $a_0=2$ and $a_1=-2$.

Comment: I realized i could solve for $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$, but since the quesetion also asked for the recurrence relation I thought I just didn't know how to solve it. The question must have a typo or something then, I was so confused when I saw this. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: Oh sorry, actually it seems they want you to try to re-express the given formula as a recurrence relation, i.e. to find the coefficients $C$ such that $a_n=C_1a_{n-1} + C_2 a_{n-2}$ where $a_n$ is as given. It is not immediate to me but you should be able to play around and solve for $C$ if its homework.

Comment: Do you know the process for this, because I"m completely lost?

Comment: I had thought you wanted to solve a linear recurrence so that was is why I commented as such at first but it appears the exercise is to find a recurrence that yields the already given solution. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh I understand its finding the problem from the solution, let me edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have stated
$$a_{n} = 2^{n}(1 + (−2)^{n})=2^n+(-4)^n$$
So the recurrence relation must have an auxiliary equation given by
$$(r-2)(r+4)=0$$
in order to have the solutions $r=2,-4$. Expanding this gives
$$r^2+2r-8=0$$
$$r^2=-2r+8$$
Hence the original recurrence relation is
$$a_n=-2a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}$$

Comment: Alright so if I'm following your solution correctly. Step 1 you distributed the $2^{n}$. Step 2 i'm a little fuzzy on the reasoning as to why r is used  but I can see what you did. Step 3 you basically found the quadratic formula that has the roots 2 and -4, and rewrote it. Step 4, you used $a_{n}= C_{1}a_{n-1}+C_{2}a_{n-2}$ to rewrite it in the correct form?

Comment: Yes, any recurrence relation of the form $a_n=C_1a_{n-1}+C_2a_{n-2}$ has an auxiliary equation $r^2-C_1r-C_2=0$ which (if having two unique solutions) gives $r_0,r_1$ for the solution $a_n=Ar_0^n+Br_1^n$. Working backwards allows one to find the original relation.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but then shouldn't it be $(r^{2} -2)$ instead of (r-2)

Comment: If $a_n$ is given by $a_n=Ar_0^n+Br_1^n$ for constants $A,B$ then the values $r_0,r_1$ are solutions to the equation $r^2-C_1r-C_2=0$. One can rewrite this as $(r-r_0)(r-r_1)=0$ for the solutions to the equation given. I then expanded this and rearranged to give $C_1,C_2$ explicitly.